# Grocery crud works on all columns except for two columns?

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

It has been three days trying to solve my form to submit correctly. I ended up installing codeigniter and grocery crud again but it's always the same problem.

If I type a url inside the input to update it in the database It will not work:

```
http://example.cc
```

but if I add a return (empty line) before it it submits correctly.,

```
(NEW LINE) 
http://example.cc
```

Meanwhile, I'm unable to update a column with html if it contains certain tags such as

```
<input>
```

just click on **project properties** and try to update the youtube video url or try to change the paypal_form

Edit: and what I find really strange is that I can update the description column of the table that came with the example (click on products link and try to put the code below and it works ) but not for project properties -> desription

Here's an example line of code that if I type the form doesnt submit :

```
 <input>
```

below is the database i'm trying to edit through grocery crud

[image]

So what can cause this problem ? my table and the table of the example have the same column types except the number of columns and their names that is different

and below is the code I'm using in my controller to produce the table:

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_theme('datatables');
    $crud->set_table('uf_object_properties');
    $crud->set_subject('Property');
    $crud->required_fields('value');
    $crud->columns('property_name', 'property_value');
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->load->view('myview.php', $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Grocery_CRUD will strip any tags from the input from a text input to make the content safe. If you want to add HTML change the datatype of your mysql column to "text" and use the HTML editor. There is probably a work around but you would need to get into the library code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after struggling a lot with it, it turned out to be a BUG in the grocery crud.

Simply, if the column name contain the letter V or something like that it wont work properly with html tags or special charachters

I started deleting column by column from the example that worked for me to make the table structure I want, after reducing all columns it was working, after that i started to rename them column by colum and once i renamed the column 'productDescription' to 'propertyValue' which is the name I wanted for the column it stopped working. So I started deleting letter by letter and found out the problem was with the column name.

Exmple of column names that produce this problem :

```
propertyValue
propertyVal
propertyV
propertyValeur
```

so I just replaced the second word value with the another word and problem was solved.

**But seriously this is a very confusing bug that needs to be fixed sooner or later**

**EDIT :**
The names above doesn't cause grocery crud to stop working at all, it just make it unable to submit such information which contain for example `<input>` or a link such as http://exmple.cc

Thanks all for the help